# Spark EventLog rollling without having History server

Tags: apache-spark

I encountered a challenge while working on a project where my application produced logs at an exceptionally high rate, causing the storage space dedicated to logs to grow into gigabytes within a few days. To address this issue, I explored the option of utilizing EventLog Rolling. The official documentation suggested using the properties spark.eventLog.rolling.enabled and spark.eventLog.rolling.maxFileSize.

However, a key concern emerged regarding the management of the number of files to retain. Since I wasn't utilizing a HistoryServer I don't know how to limit the number of files, I sought guidance on resolving this specific issue.

And please give clarity on how above thing effect the sysout and syserr logs for driver and executor when i use those in spark-submit.

Please provide some information on it. Thanks for Helping me.